# How to get the id of the object when using toggleProperty

Tags: ember.js

I would like to get the id of story object in the following template so that I can put in the comment but am not sure how to do that. I would think that the action has a reference to the object that it was called on.

I have:

```
 {{#each}}
    <div>{{date}}</div>
    {{#each stories}}
      <div {{action 'toggleProperty' 'areCommentsDisplayed'}}>{{headline}}  {{url}} {{id}}</div>

    {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
at end
<br /><br />
{{#if areCommentsDisplayed}}
   comments are displayed with {{id}}
{{else}}
   comments are NOT displayed {{id}}
{{/if}}
```

Clicking on the action doesn't cause the id to be written to the areCommentsDisplayed block in the bottom. How would I get a reference to write the id there?

Comment: Please give us the jsbin

Answer (score 0):

That's because `id` is no longer in scope outside of the `each` blocks. You need to assign the ID to a variable, then show that. For instance, I would change your action to this:

```
{{action 'toggleComments' id}}
```

Then implement the action like so:

```
toggleComments: function(id) {
    this.set('selectedId', id);
    this.toggleProperty('areCommentsDisplayed');
}
```

Now you can use `selectedId` in your `if` block, which will be in scope and contain the ID of the most recent story you clicked on.